# Array values saved as System.String[] in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with checkboxes and posting them back to the controller and saving them to as SQl Server database, the values are System.String[].  Been looking around forums for a bit looking for a solution to output the array back out as a list of selected equipment but not finding anything.  When hovering the array in the controller argument, all values that were selected in the form are listed and correct.

```
 <div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="equipmentCheckbox" id="pc" value="PC">PC
   </label>
  </div>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="equipmentCheckbox" id="monitor" value="Flat Panel Monitor">Monitor
   </label>
   </div>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="equipmentCheckbox" id="mic" value="mic">Mic
   </label>
 </div>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="equipmentCheckbox" id="speakers" value="speakers">Speakers
   </label>
 </div>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="equipmentCheckbox" id="videoPlayer" value="videoPlayer">Video player
   </label>
 </div>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="equipmentCheckbox" id="lab" value="lab">Lab
   </label>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult equipmentRequest(string[] equipmentCheckbox) 
    {
        var db = new Entities();


        string[] equipment = Request.Form.GetValues("equipmentCheckbox");

        var order = new Order
        {

            EquipmentRequested = equipment.ToString(),

        };

        db.Requests.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I'm stuck on how to parse the array to a list to save correctly to the database instead of System.String[]

Comment: what is the type of `EquipmentRequested` ? you want to parse the array to a list of what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use toString on a string array when you do

```
equipment.ToString()
```

I don't know what your purpose is with that .ToString() call, but there is your mistake.

Order should contain

```
ICollection<EquipmentRequested> EquipmentRequested { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
string EquipmentRequested { get; set; }
```

and EquipmentRequested should contain a string property 'value' and an OrderId to link the objects.

Comment: Right.  When I removed the .ToString() I'm getting an error of cannot implicity convert type string[] to string.

Comment: You need to figure out how you want to store your equipment records in the database, and build a correct datamodel for that. That's missing now, which is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: My guess would be that order should have an ICollection of strings as EquipmentRequested instead of a single string